# Trying to redirect to index1.php page

Tags: php, mysql

First time here
I know someone must have come here with a problem like mine, but trust me, I have search this site for a problem similar to mine but couldn't really find my kind of problem. The thing is I use WAMP server and my site works perfectly.

On WAMP, I have the index.php (which has the login form), I have the login.php (which connects to database and verifies login details), I have index2.php (which is I am supposed to be redirected too), I also have logout,php (which destroys sessions) and I have the session.php

All this works perfectly on my WAMP server, but when I uploaded this to a live server, I cant even log in, after some minor tweeks, I can login but i get a blank page because I get stuck at the login.php page, I am not redirected to index2.php

On WAMP, I use ("localhost","root","","modem")
but for my live server, I use ("localhost","alagbeco","a12345","alagbeco_modem")

My scripts

index.php

```
    <?php
    include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script

    if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    header("location: index2.php");
    }
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
<title>SEAP Divisional Monthly Subscription Database</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">

<br>


<div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 340px;>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="image/banner.png" alt="" align=""/></a>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>



<div style="float:left; border:2px solid #ccc; padding:10px 40px 25px; border-radius:10px; margin-left:500px; width:250px; margin-top:0px;">
<h3>Login Here</h3>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Username :</label>
<input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
<label>Password :</label>
<input id="password" name="password" type="password">
<br><br><br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
<span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
</form>
<a href="reset.php">Change password</a>
</div>
<br><br>


</body>
</html>
```

index2.php

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>

<head>

<style type="text/css">

    ul{

        padding-left: 0px;

        list-style: none;

    }

    ul li{

        float: left;

        width: 200px;

        text-align: center;

    }

    ul li a{

        display: block;

        padding: 5px 10px;

        color: #FFF;

        background: #0101DF;

        text-decoration: none;

    }

    ul li a:hover{

        color: #000000;

        background: #F7FE2E;

    }

    ul li ul{

        display: none;

    }

    ul li:hover ul{

        display: block; /* display the dropdown */

    }

</style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
<br>


<div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 340px;>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="image/banner.png" alt="" align=""/></a>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 1100px; margin-top: 0px;">
<a href="logout.php">Log out</a>
</div>
<br><br>



<!---------------------------row  begins------------------------->


<!------------------------------ibadan begins-------------------> 

<div style="height: 120px; float: left; margin-left: 375px; margin-top: 20px; width: 250px; border: 8px solid #58D3F7;">
<ul>
                <li>
                <a href="#">Ibadan Division</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="bm/ibadanbm1.php">BM Admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="sm/ibadansm1.php">SM/DAM/OM</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                </ul>
</div>
<!-----------------------------ibadan ends-------------------------->


 <!------------------------------osun begins--------------------------> 

<div style="height: 120px; float: left; margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 20px; width: 250px; border: 8px solid #58D3F7;">
<ul>
                <li>
                <a href="#">Osun Division</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="bm/osunbm1.php">BM Admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="sm/osunsm1.php">SM/DAM/OM</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                </ul>
</div>
<!------------------------------osun ends-------------------->
<br><br><br><br> 

<!--------------------row  ends------------------------------->

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</body>
```

login.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","alagbeco","a12345","alagbeco_modem");
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("alagbeco_modem", $connection);
// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
$query = mysql_query("select * from user where password = md5('$password') AND username='$username'", $connection);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
header("location: index2.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
}
}
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy()) // Destroying All Sessions
{
header("Location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

session.php

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","alagbeco","a12345","alagbeco_modem");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("alagbeco_modem", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from user where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

Comment: *"i get a blank page"* => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: blank page often means that errors are configured not to show up. Therefore, add in your main page something like : `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and then try to debug.

Comment: *"but for my live server, I use ("localhost","alagbeco","a12345","alagbeco_modem")"* - Four parameters is `mysqli_` syntax, not `mysql_` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php would have signaled the error.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost sure you have an error in your page, as alfallouji wrote.

mysql and mysqli are not the same, i suggest that you install mysqli also at your local server.

Its not hard to do, and save you a lot of debug time.

See php manual,
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

You have an error doing the connection

Try that:

```
<?php    
 $host='localhost';
 $user='alagbeco';
 $password='a12345';
 $db='alagbeco_modem';

 //If your PHP version is lower than 5.5
 $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or exit("Connection Error");
 $connection = mysql_select_db($db, $con);

 //If your PHP version is equal or higher than 5.5
 $connection =  mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I decided to change all connections to: 
 $connection =  mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
?>       But now I cant even login anymore. It says wrong username or password even though it is correct

Comment: Again, this time I used: $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or exit("Connection Error");
 $connection = mysql_select_db($db, $con);     and I can log in perfectly! Thanks guys, but now my logout.php is just a blank page, not working (although it never really worked on the live server)

Comment: Try erasing the if <?php session_start(); session_destroy();header("Location: index.php"); ?>

Comment: thanks, i can now log out successfully and i get redirected to the login page, however i noticed whenever i click on back and forward on the browser i still access the website which shouldn't be, because logging out ought to destroy all sessions, so if i click back, i'm supposed to still remain on the login page. can u help me out?